# Loading different objects from file

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, declaration

I'm trying to load A and B objects from file that would look something like

```
A 3 4
B 2 4 5
B 3 5 6
A 2 3
```

I have the following classes, Base, A and B, subclasses of Base. Each with the operator>> overloaded.

The problem is in the function load(). I'm not sure how to instanciate objects.. My load() doesn't compile because `‘pO’ was not declared in this scope`. 
How could I fix it ? Or what would be the best way to achieve this ?

Also, if I manage to make it work somehow, would I need to delete objects manually ?

```
class Base
{
    public:
        Base() {}
        Base(int tot_) : tot(tot_) {}

        void print() const {
            std::cout << "Tot : " << tot << std::endl; 
        }

    private:
        int tot;
};

class A : public Base
{
    public:
        A() : Base(0) {}
        A(int a1, int a2) : Base(a1+a2) {}
};


class B : public Base
{
    public:
        B() : Base(1) {}
        B(int b1, int b2, int b3) : Base(b1+b2+b3){}
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, A& a)
{ 
    int a1, a2;
    in >> a1; 
    in >> a2;

    a = A(a1,a2);

    return in;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, B& b)
{ 
    int b1, b2, b3;
    in >> b1; 
    in >> b2;
    in >> b3;

    b = B(b1,b2,b3);

    return in;
}

bool load(const std::string& s, std::vector<Base*>& objs)
{
    std::ifstream is(s.c_str());
    if (is.good())
    {
        std::string obj;
        while (!is.eof()) 
        {
            is >> obj;
            if (obj == "A") {
                A *pO = new A;
            }
            else (obj == "B") {
                B *pO = new B;
            }
            is >> *pO;
            objs.push_back(pO);
        }
        is.close();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare `pO` in the scope where you use it:

```
        is >> obj;
        Base *pO;
        if (obj == "A") {
            A *a = new A;
            is >> *a;
            pO = a;
        }
        else { // (obj == "B")
            B *b = new B;
            is >> *b;
            pO = b;
        }
        objs.push_back(pO);
```

Comment: I guess you meant Base *pO

Comment: Yes, I skipped the declarations and thought that B was a subclass of A.

Comment: That did it, thanks. Do you know if I need to delete those objects manually or do they die when vector objs dies ?

Comment: But only after you're done with them! That is, at the end of the program, when you're discarding the `objs` vector.

Answer (score 0):

And the answer to your other question, "would I need to delete objects manually" is yes, objects allocated with `new` always need to be delete with `delete`.

However, since you push the pointers to an array, make sure not to delete them too early, when they're still in use!

So one alternate solution would be to not use pointers. Make `obj` an array of `Base` rather than an array of `Base*` and avoid any `new` or `delete`.

Edit:
Without pointers, I'd be writing something like this:

```
while (!is.eof()) {
    is >> obj;
    if (obj == "A") {
        A pO; 
        is >> pO;
        objs.push_back(pO);
    }
    else if (obj == "B") {
        B pO;
        is >> pO;
        objs.push_back(pO);
    }
}
```

but make sure not to cause any object slicing by adding member variables to either class A or class B!

Comment: I'll gladly do that but how would that look like in load() ? I went with pointers thinking I couldn't have a vector<Base> filled with A and B.

Comment: OK, I edited. But I just realise that with an array of Base, you'd be slicing your objects. So if you're planning to add member variables to your class, add them to the base class, not to the derived classes! (Or stick with pointers, but remember to delete them before disposing the `objs` vector.)